# The Implode function in PHP isn't showing up my results in a js chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

Im using the `implode()` function for 2 items in a bar chart:

1.) For the checkPoint (Which is an integer value and this gives the bar chart the values `data` which is held under data in the js code). Which works perfectly

2.) For the module names (which is just Strings, the names of the module). which I paste under `labels`

However the names of the columns in my bar chart (module names) under the labels is not showing up, however in the inspect element of my web page, they are being shown there. The error is the console is: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'ManagementCareer'. Expected either a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element.`

**The code:**

```
$query = "SELECT `module`.`ModuleName`,`userTakingModule`.`checkPoint` FROM `userTakingModule` JOIN `module`ON `userTakingModule`.`ModuleID`= `module`.`ModuleID` JOIN `users`ON `userTakingModule`.`idUsers`=`users`.`idUsers` WHERE `userTakingModule`.`idUsers`=  '".$_SESSION['id']."' ";

    //Execute
    $result = $conn -> query($query);

    $moduleCheckPoint = Array();
    $moduleName = Array();


    while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) 
          {
            $moduleCheckPoint[] = $row['checkPoint'];
            $moduleName[] = $row['ModuleName'];

          }

<?php
    $modCheckPoint = implode(',',$moduleCheckPoint);
    $modName = implode(',', $moduleName);
?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("my3Chart");
                    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: {
                            labels: [<?php echo $modName ?>],
                            datasets: [{
                                label: 'Module Tracker',
                                data: [<?php echo $modCheckPoint ?>],
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                                ],
                                borderColor: [
                                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                                ],
                                borderWidth: 1
                            }]
                        },
                        options: {
                            scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero:true
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    </script>
```

The module check point is working fine and populating the bar chart, however the module names are not appearing at all. Please can someone highlight what I've done incorrectly?

What should be appearing (moduleNames):
[image: modulenames]

Under Inspect Element they are showing:

[image: Inspect Element under console]

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct approach here is to use `json_encode` function:

```
$modCheckPoint = json_encode($moduleCheckPoint);
// though `$moduleName` is array of numbers - you can leave `implode`
// but in case of array strings - always use `json_encode`
$modName = implode(',', $moduleName);
```

Also:

```
labels: <?php echo $modName ?>,  // remove [] here, as `json_encode` returns them already.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I have tried this and the chart does now appear on screen however it's now used the 6 module names all as 1 module name and not split them, I almost need the `,` in between each module name so the js chart knows there are various names?

Comment: Thank you so much, that's weird as that `[]` I thought was just to do with the javascript code as thats where the "strings", would be held, thank you so much!